# How would I extract this data from JSON and put it in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to use this code, and extract the data from it and add it to a table. 
I got a JSFiddle link, the code to add it to the table is not working. Not sure, but it is to do with the JSON array ?

http://jsfiddle.net/T7eQg/213/

```
        $(function(){

        var jsonObj = $.parseJSON('{"deals":{"items":[{"title":"Stripe Cashmere Blend Jumper \u00c2\u00a36 at George (Free C&C)","deal_link":"http:\/\/www.hotukdeals.com\/deals\/stripe-cashmere-blend-jumper-6-george-free-c-c-2390139?aui=1047","mobile_deal_link":"http:\/\/www.hotukdeals.com\/deals\/stripe-cashmere-blend-jumper-6-george-free-c-c-2390139?aui=1047","deal_image":"http:\/\/static.hotukdeals.com\/images\/threads\/2390139_1.jpg","description":"Update your winter essentials with this gorgeous stripe cashmere jumper. This lovely jumper designed with contrast stripe sleeves, will be an awesome update to your weekly rotation.\n\nbb8 ;)","submit_time":"7 hours, 29 minutes ago","hot_time":"3 hours, 3 minutes ago","poster_name":"bb8","temperature":129.08,"price":"6.00","timestamp":1454709758,"expired":"false","forum":{"name":"Deals","url_name":"deals"},"category":{"name":"Fashion","url_name":"fashion"},"merchant":{"name":"George (Asda George)","url_name":"direct.asda.com-1"},"tags":{"items":[]},"deal_image_highres":"http:\/\/static.hotukdeals.com\/images\/threads\/high-res\/2390139_1.jpg","deal_image_highres_width":372,"deal_image_highres_height":500},{"title":"12 pack polo mint for \u00c2\u00a31 Instore @ FarmFoods","deal_link":"http:\/\/www.hotukdeals.com\/deals\/12-pack-polo-mint-for-1-instore-farmfoods-2389584?aui=1047","mobile_deal_link":"http:\/\/www.hotukdeals.com\/deals\/12-pack-polo-mint-for-1-instore-farmfoods-2389584?aui=1047","deal_image":"http:\/\/static.hotukdeals.com\/images\/threads\/2389584_1.jpg","description":"12 pack polo mint for \u00c2\u00a31 Instore ","submit_time":"20 hours, 30 minutes ago","hot_time":"3 hours, 21 minutes ago","poster_name":"bulktrans","temperature":117,"price":"1.00","timestamp":1454662886,"expired":"false","forum":{"name":"Deals","url_name":"deals"},"category":{"name":"Groceries","url_name":"groceries"},"merchant":{"name":"FarmFoods","url_name":"farmfoods.co.uk"},"tags":{"items":[{"name":"Farmfoods"},{"name":"Polo Shirt"}]},"deal_image_highres":"http:\/\/static.hotukdeals.com\/images\/threads\/high-res\/2389584_1.jpg","deal_image_highres_width":500,"deal_image_highres_height":375}]},"total_results":1000}');
        var html = '<table border="1">';
        $.each(jsonObj.deals.items, function(key, value){
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td>' + value.title + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + value.description + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + value.price + '</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
        });
        html += '</table>';

        $('div').html(html);
    });
```

Comment: look at error thrown in browser dev tools console. Something in the json is causing it to be invalid. Paste it into a json validator like jsonlint.com. Could be a bad line break also

Comment: It's better if you tell us what is the error.

Comment: Please remove $.parseJSON function .

I have updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T7eQg/216/

Comment: Thanks all working now, this JSON data is static, would you lot know how to get live data ? I am using a API and don't know how to get it from a URL, and have it working in my files.

Comment: You'd need to read the Docs for the API for that information.....how could we tell you that, when you havent told us what API you are using.....though it will likely involve `ajax`

Comment: Sorry this is all new to me, its hot uk deals API, I will be seeing my lecturers on Monday, but for now I want to try do something myself. As I got a deadline coming up. So the hotukdeals API url displays that JSON, and I have to retrieve the data, then extract it and put it in a table on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem:

The thing in your JSON that breaks the parsing is...

...the two `\n` characters in the JSON data!

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/T7eQg/219/

### The Explanation:

`\n` is parsed by Javascript at runtime, resulting in an actual line break in your JSON data. This means that it is no longer valid code and results in a browser error. The problem can be easily avoided if you use `\\n` instead, as this escapes the backslash as being a normal backslash rather than part of `\n`.

The next time it is parsed, `\n` will form again and make the intended line break.

### Other Info:

- `\r` is the same as `\n` (in the fact that it causes a line break and should be escaped)
- Here is where the **two** `\n`s are in your code:
  `... to your weekly rotation.\n\nbb8 ;)"...`